# Does SQL Server even look at a table when joining on a variable that returns false?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I join table A to table B like this...

```
select A.* from A 
left outer join B on A.Id = B.aId and @param = 'someValue'
```

and @param does not equal 'someValue', does SQL Server even attempt to match records from table B or is it smart enough to know the condition will never be true?

Comment: Why would you ever do this? Or is it just a hypothetical?

Comment: I was trying to find an efficient way to write a query whose criteria could exist in 1 of 15 different tables depending on a parameter that indicated which table.

Comment: Sounds like that's your root problem and this is just a symptom of that. What kind of query spans 15 different entities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- As a general rule, SQL [does not guarantee runtime boolean operator short-circuit](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/).
- The query plan would have to work for *any* value of @param because plans are reused between executions

So while in a particular context you may find that the when @param has a different value then the outer join table may never be *probed*, you should not rely on it for correctness. Note that probe means that actual values are searched for in the table. The metadata information will *always* be checked. For example you cannot cheat and ask for a join to a table that doesn't exists.

In particular, do not attempt to create a single query where there should be two different ones (one that joins, one that doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to put this code in a new answer rather than a comment, but this shows a bit of what Remus is saying:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test_Params
    @param1 INT
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        o.object_id,
        c.object_id
    FROM
        sys.objects o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.columns c ON
        c.object_id = o.object_id AND
        @param1 = 1
    OPTION
        (RECOMPILE)
END
GO


EXEC dbo.Test_Params 1
EXEC dbo.Test_Params 2
```

If you do an execution plan on the two EXEC statements, you'll see that sys.columns appears in both execution plans, but in the second the rows are all filtered before the join takes place. Notice that they are not short-circuited out of the query entirely though.